# Node.js handling response from http request

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, httprequest

I have some code as follows:

```
exports.post = function(request, response) {

  var httpRequest = require('request');
  var uri = "url..";

  httpRequest(uri, function(err, responseHeaders, bodyResponse) {
    var data = JSON.parse(bodyResponse); 
  });

}
```

I want to use the data outside the httprequest, but inside the exports.post function.
In all the examples I have seen, everyone uses the body for logging, but I want to use the data.

Comment: You can't.  The `exports.post` function has completed by the time the data is there.  Why can't you use the data inside the `httprequest`?

Comment: Because i am making  a couple of requests and then i want to join the data..

Comment: You probably want a library like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join requests data, you could use Promises in this case:

```
function joinData() {
    var httpRequest = require('request');
    var url1 = 'http://echo.jsontest.com/request/first';
    var url2 = 'http://echo.jsontest.com/request/second';

    var promisedRequest = function (uri) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            httpRequest(uri, function (err, responseHeaders, bodyResponse) {
                var data = JSON.parse(bodyResponse);
                resolve(data);
            });
        });
    }

    // both requests at the same time
    Promise.all([promisedRequest(url1), promisedRequest(url2)])
        .then(function (responsesArray) {
            console.log(responsesArray);        // <- your responses here
        });
}
```